# Pagination in Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, extjs, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.2.4, Zend Framework 11 and ExtJS 3.4 in my project. So I have tables in my database with thousands of records like Students. So I retrieve these data using DQL language, and then I need paginate these data and I use Doctrine_Pager.
In most cases I don't have any problem to retrieve data but when I add a where clause in my DQL and use something like this

```
where("st.name ~* 'a'")
```

and return a Doctrine error. How can I solve it??

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: el operador no existe: text ~* st_name
```

Comment: What does operator `~*` stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Your where statement is wrong, shouldn't u use `where st.name like '*a'`?